# How to deal with repetitiveness and flexibility when implementing Go interfaces?

Tags: go

I have a project that uses a structure like so:

```
type I interface {
  GetName() string
  DoSomething()
}

//
// A implements I
//
type A struct {
    Name  string
}

func (a *A) GetName() string {
  return a.Name
}

func (a *A) DoSomething() {
  ...do something
}

//
// B implements I
//
type B struct {
    Name  string
}

func (b *B) GetName() string {
  return b.Name
}

func (b *B) DoSomething() {
  ...do something
}

func (b *B) DoSomethingElse() {
  ...do something else
}

//
// Both
//
func UseAorB(T I) {
  name := T.GetName()...
}
```

1. Is using GetName the best way to get the name field from either struct A or B when called in a function that takes interface I?
2. Do I have to redefine DoSomething every time for each thing that is meant to implement the interface? Or is there a better way to do this if DoSomething is the same every time where I can define it just once?
3. Struct B has a method that the interface does not define (DoSomethingElse). Do I need to use reflect to be able to pass Struct B to a function that takes interface I to call DoSomethingElse? Or should I be defining a new interface that includes this method?

I want to improve my code quality and write a solid library, but I have to say it feels like I am fighting the language and making my life more difficult.

Comment: If every implementation of the interface is exactly the same, it probably means you don't need an interface.

Comment: Until you give some explanation of what `DoSomething` actually does, it will be hard to advise what structure you should use.

Comment: Related / possible duplicate: [Wrapping multiple implementations in Go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48932657/wrapping-multiple-implementations-in-go/48933367#48933367); and [Generic Method Parameters in Golang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28393166/generic-method-parameters-in-golang/28393465#28393465)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Yes, `GetName()` is a good way of doing that
2. If you have similar implementations of a method, you can usually move it to a common struct and embed that:

   ```
   type Common struct {}

   func (c Common) DoSomething() {...}

   type A struct {
      Common
      Stuff
   }

   type B struct {
      Common
      Other stuff
   }
   ```

   Above, both `A` and `B` have `DoSomething` method, and they share the implementation
3. Do not use reflect. There are two ways:

   1. Use type assertion:

      ```
      func f(in I) {
         if b, ok:=in.(B); ok {
            // b is of type B, so:
            b.DoSomethingElse()
         }
      }
      ```

   2. Use an interface and type assertion:

      ```
      type DoesSometingElse interface {
         DoSomethingElse()
      }

      func f(in I) {
         if x, ok:=in.(DoesSomethingElse); ok{
            x.DoSomethingElse()
         }
      }
      ```

If you feel like you're fighting with the language, then either you are modeling something incorrectly, or you don't know the right way to do something in that language. There are good and bad ways of doing things in all languages, and many times these are different for each language. If you are coming to Go from another language, you should first stop trying to think in that other language and translate to Go, and try to work with Go alone.

Comment: Absolutely excellent. Embedding the struct is the best way to share common functionality between multiple instances of structs that implement the same interface.